# in c# are methods private by default?

Tags: c#

If I have a method that does not specify its Accessibility Level will it be Private by default?

```
void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Is the above method private?

Comment: @Cloud - but you don't get any reputation points that way ;)

Comment: @Cloud - I wanted a more scientific answer. When VS automatically generates a method stub it creates the method with Private accessibility - not without any Accessibility keyword.

Comment: it does that according to the same rule that Julien Lebosquain explains in his answer. You can see it as a kind of 'better safe than sorry'-approach to generation. It's better to have less accessibility and a compilation error (in the future), than too much accessibility you don't know of. :) Also, there are probably also performance related reasons for this behaviour.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It is. The general rule if you don't define any modifier is "the most restricted modifier that can be applied here is used", so private for methods, internal for top-level classes, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is private.

Answer (score 4):

For a method inside a class, default is private.  It does vary based on the scope of where things are declared, here's an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(VS.80).aspx) with more specifics

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for methods, like your example.

> Class and struct members, including nested classes and structs, have
> private access by default.

But that is not correct for all the access modifiers:

> Classes, records, and structs declared directly within a namespace (in
> other words, that aren't nested within other classes or structs) can
> be either public or internal. internal is the default if no access
> modifier is specified.

I consider this a good idea, because by default in OO, everything should be private and only what is really needed should be marked public.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers